# Oracle Database Error At Startup of Windows 10

Tags: oracle

i have an error which is driving me crazy and i dont know how to deal with it. In a PC with windows 10 64-bit , i got an oracle database server 11g. Everytime the pc restarts or shuts down and then restarts i get the following error when i try to connect to the database :

ORA-01033: ORACLE initialization or shutdown in progress
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0

the only way to get my database running is the following one:

open a cmd and type :

```
rman target / 
recover database;
shutdown immediate;
startup mount;
alter database open resetlogs;
```

after that everything is fine , but if i restart the PC i get the same error again.

Has anyone dealted with anything like this before?

I have checked the hard disk and is ok, have defragmented it, have run test diagnostics, it is driving me crazy. Any idea would be welcome!

Thanx in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a pretty general error. Your database can have issues with either starting up or maybe shuting down cleanly.

I would recommend you looking at the end of the alert.log file right after the server is started, before performing rman recovery.

You can find hints there as why the database did not started up to open state, where and why it is hanging, etc.

EDIT: So the error is `ORA-00600 [dbkif_find_next_record_1]`

Whenever an ORA-00600, or ORA-00700 or ORA-07445 occurs, this is an internal error within Oracle core. For this cases there is this neat tool at http://support.oracle.com which can search the knowledge base of Oracle MySupport network and try to find existing articles and/or patches, hotfixes for respective arguments of these internal errors.

The tool can be found as Oracle Support `Doc ID 153788.1`.

Unfortunatelly, the lookup tool did not found anything for argument `ORA-00600 [dbkif_find_next_record_1]`. In that case please make sure that your OS is updated and supported. Also if you are running on VM, that the VM has all parameters set according to Oracle's recommendations and if there is nothing suspicious there, you will have to open "Service request" at http://support.oracle.com

Comment: Hello! i get this one :

Errors in file c:\ora11gsrv\diag\rdbms\srs2\srs2\trace\srs2_ora_3452.trc:
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [dbkif_find_next_record_1], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
ORA-600 signalled during: alter database open...

Comment: there is no VM , the oracle server was working fine till a week ago when this error started , i am losing my mind with it, anyway thanx for your time ,

Comment: You can also try to install new Oracle DB and clone the database there. You will see... But definitelly go with the Service Request.